# Sequelize - filtering posts based on term in title?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

i am trying to filter my posts table based on a parameter that the user inputs into the search bar in the frontend (react native). I am using sequelize as my ORM.

I have tried implementing the following but my problem is when i test on postman is that i am not getting all the correct search results i require.

```
router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
let {term}=req.query;
term=term.toLowerCase()
Post.findAll({where:{title:{[Op.like]: '%' + term + '%' }},
order: ["createdAt"]}).then(posts=>res.send(posts)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with my code. It was in the term.toLowerCase().

Works if i do as follow:

```
router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
let {term}=req.query;
Post.findAll({where:{title:{[Op.iLike]: '%' + term + '%' }},
order: 
["createdAt"]}).then(posts=>res.send(posts)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
```